# Mysql to json.....how to find out the right query

Tags: android, mysql, xml, json

I'm implementing an alternative android market, I have the mysql and I'm implementing the android client. Android will interact with mysql tnx o php that will translate mysql query result in json, but this layer at the moment doesn't exist. So I'm making query manually through phpmyadmin, exporting the query result in XML (cause you can't export straight o json) an then converting he XML to json with a online XML to json converter ex. http://extjs.org.cn/xml2json/xml2json_online.php

Now I did the first activity of my android client that shows the list of all the apps available. That was easy caue all the data i need where in the Table APPLICAZIONE.
Now when i click on a app it should open the detail of that application like in the android market. The problem is the this new page requires more info cause it shows also the details of the Developper, the preview images of the app, the ratings of the app and the user that wrote it and so on.........so basically I have to query not only 1 table but 5 different tables in a join:

This is the query I tried:

```
SELECT `APPLICAZIONE_ID` , `APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO` , `APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH` , `APPLICAZIONE_NOME` , `APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE` , `APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM` , `APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI` ,`ID_SVILUPPATORE` ,
   `SVILUPPATORE_NOME` , `SVILUPPATORE_MAIL` , `SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE`, `SVILUPPATORE_ID`,
       `IMMAGINE_PATH`, immagine_preview.`ID_APPLICAZIONE`,
       `RATING_DATA` , `RATING_VOTO` , `RATING_DESCRIZIONE` , `ID_UTENTE`,  rating.`ID_APPLICAZIONE`,
       `UTENTE_USERID` , `UTENTE_ID`
FROM `applicazione` , `sviluppatore`,`immagine_preview`,`rating`,`utente`
WHERE applicazione.`APPLICAZIONE_ID` =1
      AND applicazione.`ID_SVILUPPATORE` = sviluppatore.`SVILUPPATORE_ID`
      AND applicazione.`APPLICAZIONE_ID` = immagine_preview.`ID_APPLICAZIONE`
      AND applicazione.`APPLICAZIONE_ID` = rating.`ID_APPLICAZIONE`
      AND utente.`UTENTE_ID` = rating.`ID_UTENTE`
```

In Phpmyadmin i get 9 rows, it's corrwct cause i know how i filled up the db, i have 1 app with that ID, thta has 1 developper (so   still 1 record) but then the app has 3 preview images (so 1x3  3 record) and 3 ratings left by some users (so 3x3 = 9 records).

If i export the result in sql this is what I get:

```
<marketmddb>
     <!-- Tabella applicazione -->
        <applicazione>
            <APPLICAZIONE_ID>1</APPLICAZIONE_ID>
            <APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>4.5</APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>
        <APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>D:\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\icone\search1.png</APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NOME>Applicazione1</APPLICAZIONE_NOME>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>La prima app di prova</APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>10</APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>5</APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>
        <ID_SVILUPPATORE>1</ID_SVILUPPATORE>
        <SVILUPPATORE_NOME>Luca</SVILUPPATORE_NOME>
        <SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>sviluppatore@mail.com</SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>
        <SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>www.pirla.it</SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>
        <SVILUPPATORE_ID>1</SVILUPPATORE_ID>
        <IMMAGINE_PATH>percorso1</IMMAGINE_PATH>
        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
        <RATING_DATA>2011-05-10 14:21:32</RATING_DATA>
        <RATING_VOTO>3</RATING_VOTO>
        <RATING_DESCRIZIONE>Questa applicazione funziona come i prodotti della marcuzzi</RATING_DESCRIZIONE>
        <ID_UTENTE>1</ID_UTENTE>
        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
        <UTENTE_USERID>Luca</UTENTE_USERID>
        <UTENTE_ID>1</UTENTE_ID>
    </applicazione>
    <applicazione>
        <APPLICAZIONE_ID>1</APPLICAZIONE_ID>
        <APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>4.5</APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>
        <APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>D:\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\icone\search1.png</APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NOME>Applicazione1</APPLICAZIONE_NOME>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>La prima app di prova</APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>10</APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>5</APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>
        <ID_SVILUPPATORE>1</ID_SVILUPPATORE>
        <SVILUPPATORE_NOME>Luca</SVILUPPATORE_NOME>
        <SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>sviluppatore@mail.com</SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>
        <SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>www.pirla.it</SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>
        <SVILUPPATORE_ID>1</SVILUPPATORE_ID>
        <IMMAGINE_PATH>percorso1</IMMAGINE_PATH>
        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
        <RATING_DATA>2011-05-09 14:22:30</RATING_DATA>
        <RATING_VOTO>5</RATING_VOTO>
        <RATING_DESCRIZIONE>questa applicazione è stata fatta da un vero genio dell'informatica</RATING_DESCRIZIONE>
        <ID_UTENTE>2</ID_UTENTE>
        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
        <UTENTE_USERID>Francesco</UTENTE_USERID>
        <UTENTE_ID>2</UTENTE_ID>
    </applicazione>
    <applicazione>
        <APPLICAZIONE_ID>1</APPLICAZIONE_ID>
        <APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>4.5</APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>
        <APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>D:\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\icone\search1.png</APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NOME>Applicazione1</APPLICAZIONE_NOME>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>La prima app di prova</APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>10</APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>5</APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>
        <ID_SVILUPPATORE>1</ID_SVILUPPATORE>
        <SVILUPPATORE_NOME>Luca</SVILUPPATORE_NOME>
        <SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>sviluppatore@mail.com</SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>
        <SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>www.pirla.it</SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>
        <SVILUPPATORE_ID>1</SVILUPPATORE_ID>
        <IMMAGINE_PATH>percorso1</IMMAGINE_PATH>
        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
        <RATING_DATA>2011-05-10 14:23:23</RATING_DATA>
        <RATING_VOTO>1</RATING_VOTO>
        <RATING_DESCRIZIONE>Non ci siamo proprio</RATING_DESCRIZIONE>
        <ID_UTENTE>3</ID_UTENTE>
        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
        <UTENTE_USERID>Vanessa</UTENTE_USERID>
        <UTENTE_ID>3</UTENTE_ID>
    </applicazione>
    <applicazione>
        <APPLICAZIONE_ID>1</APPLICAZIONE_ID>
        <APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>4.5</APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>
        <APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>D:\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\icone\search1.png</APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NOME>Applicazione1</APPLICAZIONE_NOME>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>La prima app di prova</APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>10</APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>5</APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>
        <ID_SVILUPPATORE>1</ID_SVILUPPATORE>
        <SVILUPPATORE_NOME>Luca</SVILUPPATORE_NOME>
        <SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>sviluppatore@mail.com</SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>
        <SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>www.pirla.it</SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>
        <SVILUPPATORE_ID>1</SVILUPPATORE_ID>
        <IMMAGINE_PATH>percorso2</IMMAGINE_PATH>
        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
        <RATING_DATA>2011-05-10 14:21:32</RATING_DATA>
        <RATING_VOTO>3</RATING_VOTO>
        <RATING_DESCRIZIONE>Questa applicazione funziona come i prodotti della marcuzzi</RATING_DESCRIZIONE>
        <ID_UTENTE>1</ID_UTENTE>
        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
        <UTENTE_USERID>Luca</UTENTE_USERID>
        <UTENTE_ID>1</UTENTE_ID>
    </applicazione>
    and so on 9 times, if i don't cut it i will finish characters
</marketmddb>
```

and then this JSON:

```
    {
        "marketmddb":
        {
                "applicazione":
                [
                        {
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ID":"1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO":"4.5",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH":"D:\\EasyPHP5.2.10\\www\\icone\\search1.png",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NOME":"Applicazione1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE":"La prima app di prova",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM":"10",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI":"5",
                                "ID_SVILUPPATORE":"1",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_NOME":"Luca",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_MAIL":"sviluppatore@mail.com",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE":"www.pirla.it",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_ID":"1",
                                "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso1",
                                "ID_APPLICAZIONE":["1","1"],
                                "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-10 14:21:32",
                                "RATING_VOTO":"3",
                                "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"Questa applicazione funziona come i prodotti della marcuzzi",
                                "ID_UTENTE":"1",
                                "UTENTE_USERID":"Luca",
                                "UTENTE_ID":"1"
                        },
                        {
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ID":"1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO":"4.5",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH":"D:\\EasyPHP5.2.10\\www\\icone\\search1.png",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NOME":"Applicazione1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE":"La prima app di prova",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM":"10",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI":"5",
                                "ID_SVILUPPATORE":"1",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_NOME":"Luca",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_MAIL":"sviluppatore@mail.com",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE":"www.pirla.it",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_ID":"1",
                                "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso1",
                                "ID_APPLICAZIONE":["1","1"],
                                "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-09 14:22:30",
                                "RATING_VOTO":"5",
                                "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"questa applicazione \u00e8 stata fatta da un vero genio dell'informatica",
                                "ID_UTENTE":"2",
                                "UTENTE_USERID":"Francesco",
                                "UTENTE_ID":"2"
                        },
                        {
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ID":"1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO":"4.5",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH":"D:\\EasyPHP5.2.10\\www\\icone\\search1.png",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NOME":"Applicazione1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE":"La prima app di prova",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM":"10",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI":"5",
                                "ID_SVILUPPATORE":"1",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_NOME":"Luca",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_MAIL":"sviluppatore@mail.com",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE":"www.pirla.it",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_ID":"1",
                                "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso1",
                                "ID_APPLICAZIONE":["1","1"],
                                "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-10 14:23:23",
                                "RATING_VOTO":"1",
                                "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"Non ci siamo proprio",
                                "ID_UTENTE":"3",
                                "UTENTE_USERID":"Vanessa",
                                "UTENTE_ID":"3"
                        },
                        {
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ID":"1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO":"4.5",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH":"D:\\EasyPHP5.2.10\\www\\icone\\search1.png",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NOME":"Applicazione1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE":"La prima app di prova",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM":"10",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI":"5",
                                "ID_SVILUPPATORE":"1",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_NOME":"Luca",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_MAIL":"sviluppatore@mail.com",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE":"www.pirla.it",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_ID":"1",
                                "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso2",
                                "ID_APPLICAZIONE":["1","1"],
                                "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-10 14:21:32",
                                "RATING_VOTO":"3",
                                "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"Questa applicazione funziona come i prodotti della marcuzzi",
                                "ID_UTENTE":"1",
                                "UTENTE_USERID":"Luca",
                                "UTENTE_ID":"1"
                        },
                        {
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ID":"1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO":"4.5",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH":"D:\\EasyPHP5.2.10\\www\\icone\\search1.png",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NOME":"Applicazione1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE":"La prima app di prova",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM":"10",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI":"5",
                                "ID_SVILUPPATORE":"1",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_NOME":"Luca",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_MAIL":"sviluppatore@mail.com",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE":"www.pirla.it",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_ID":"1",
                                "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso2",
                                "ID_APPLICAZIONE":["1","1"],
                                "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-09 14:22:30",
                                "RATING_VOTO":"5",
                                "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"questa applicazione \u00e8 stata fatta da un vero genio dell'informatica",
                                "ID_UTENTE":"2",
                                "UTENTE_USERID":"Francesco",
                                "UTENTE_ID":"2"
                        },
                        {
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ID":"1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO":"4.5",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH":"D:\\EasyPHP5.2.10\\www\\icone\\search1.png",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NOME":"Applicazione1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE":"La prima app di prova",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM":"10",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI":"5",
                                "ID_SVILUPPATORE":"1",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_NOME":"Luca",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_MAIL":"sviluppatore@mail.com",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE":"www.pirla.it",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_ID":"1",
                                "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso2",
                                "ID_APPLICAZIONE":["1","1"],
                                "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-10 14:23:23",
                                "RATING_VOTO":"1",
                                "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"Non ci siamo proprio",
                                "ID_UTENTE":"3",
                                "UTENTE_USERID":"Vanessa",
                                "UTENTE_ID":"3"
                        },
                        {
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ID":"1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO":"4.5",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH":"D:\\EasyPHP5.2.10\\www\\icone\\search1.png",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NOME":"Applicazione1",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE":"La prima app di prova",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM":"10",
                                "APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI":"5",
                                "ID_SVILUPPATORE":"1",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_NOME":"Luca",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_MAIL":"sviluppatore@mail.com",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE":"www.pirla.it",
                                "SVILUPPATORE_ID":"1",
                                "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso3",
                                "ID_APPLICAZIONE":["1","1"],
                                "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-10 14:21:32",
                                "RATING_VOTO":"3",
                                "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"Questa applicazione funziona come i prodotti della marcuzzi",
                                "ID_UTENTE":"1",
                                "UTENTE_USERID":"Luca",
                                "UTENTE_ID":"1"
                        }

                    cut again for soaace reason

                ]
        }
}
```

As you can see this is not what want it looks like it i had 9 different applications, and there is a huge data redundancy.

What I'd like to get instead is this xml:

```
 <marketmddb>
  <!-- Tabella applicazione -->
    <applicazione>
        <APPLICAZIONE_ID>1</APPLICAZIONE_ID>
        <APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>4.5</APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO>
        <APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>D:\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\icone\search1.png</APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NOME>Applicazione1</APPLICAZIONE_NOME>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>La prima app di prova</APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE>
        <APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>10</APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM>
        <APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>5</APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI>
        <ID_SVILUPPATORE>1</ID_SVILUPPATORE>
                <sviluppatore>
                        <SVILUPPATORE_NOME>Luca</SVILUPPATORE_NOME>
                        <SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>sviluppatore@mail.com</SVILUPPATORE_MAIL>
                        <SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>www.pirla.it</SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE>
                        <SVILUPPATORE_ID>1</SVILUPPATORE_ID>
                </sviluppatore>


                <immagini>
                        <immagine_preview>
                                        <IMMAGINE_PATH>percorso1</IMMAGINE_PATH>
                                        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
                        </immagine_preview>
                        <immagine_preview>
                                        <IMMAGINE_PATH>percorso2</IMMAGINE_PATH>
                                        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
                        </immagine_preview>
                        <immagine_preview>
                                        <IMMAGINE_PATH>percorso3</IMMAGINE_PATH>
                                        <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
                        </immagine_preview>
                </immagini>

                <ratings>
                        <rating>
                                <RATING_DATA>2011-05-10 14:21:32</RATING_DATA>
                                <RATING_VOTO>3</RATING_VOTO>
                                <RATING_DESCRIZIONE>Questa applicazione funziona come i prodotti della marcuzzi</RATING_DESCRIZIONE>
                                <ID_UTENTE>1</ID_UTENTE>
                                <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
                                <utente>
                                        <UTENTE_USERID>Vanessa</UTENTE_USERID>
                                        <UTENTE_ID>1</UTENTE_ID>
                                </utente>
                        </rating>
                        <rating>
                                <RATING_DATA>2011-05-09 14:22:30</RATING_DATA>
                                <RATING_VOTO>5</RATING_VOTO>
                                <RATING_DESCRIZIONE>questa applicazione è stata fatta da un vero genio dell'informatica</RATING_DESCRIZIONE>
                                <ID_UTENTE>2</ID_UTENTE>
                                <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
                                <utente>
                                        <UTENTE_USERID>Francesco</UTENTE_USERID>
                                        <UTENTE_ID>1</UTENTE_ID>
                                </utente>
                        </rating>
                        <rating>
                                <RATING_DATA>2011-05-10 14:23:23</RATING_DATA>
                                <RATING_VOTO>1</RATING_VOTO>
                                <RATING_DESCRIZIONE>Non ci siamo proprio</RATING_DESCRIZIONE>
                                <ID_UTENTE>3</ID_UTENTE>
                                <ID_APPLICAZIONE>1</ID_APPLICAZIONE>
                                <utente>
                                        <UTENTE_USERID>Luca</UTENTE_USERID>
                                        <UTENTE_ID>1</UTENTE_ID>
                                </utente>
                        </rating>
                </ratings>
    </applicazione>
</marketmddb>
```

and then this JSON:

```
{
    "marketmddb":
    {
            "applicazione":
            {
                    "APPLICAZIONE_ID":"1",
                    "APPLICAZIONE_PREZZO":"4.5",
                    "APPLICAZIONE_ICONA_PATH":"D:\\EasyPHP5.2.10\\www\\icone\\search1.png",
                    "APPLICAZIONE_NOME":"Applicazione1",
                    "APPLICAZIONE_DESCRIZIONE":"La prima app di prova",
                    "APPLICAZIONE_DOWNLOAD_NUM":"10",
                    "APPLICAZIONE_NUM_VOTI":"5",
                    "ID_SVILUPPATORE":"1",
                    "sviluppatore":
                    {
                            "SVILUPPATORE_NOME":"Luca",
                            "SVILUPPATORE_MAIL":"sviluppatore@mail.com",
                            "SVILUPPATORE_WEB_SITE":"www.pirla.it",
                            "SVILUPPATORE_ID":"1"
                    },
                    "immagini":
                    {
                            "immagine_preview":
                            [
                                    {
                                            "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso1",
                                            "ID_APPLICAZIONE":"1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso2",
                                            "ID_APPLICAZIONE":"1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "IMMAGINE_PATH":"percorso3",
                                            "ID_APPLICAZIONE":"1"
                                    }
                            ]
                    },
                    "ratings":
                    {
                            "rating":
                            [
                                    {
                                            "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-10 14:21:32",
                                            "RATING_VOTO":"3",
                                            "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"Questa applicazione funziona come i prodotti della marcuzzi",
                                            "ID_UTENTE":"1",
                                            "ID_APPLICAZIONE":"1",
                                            "utente":
                                            {
                                                    "UTENTE_USERID":"Vanessa",
                                                    "UTENTE_ID":"1"
                                            }
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-09 14:22:30",
                                            "RATING_VOTO":"5",
                                            "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"questa applicazione \u00e8 stata fatta da un vero genio dell'informatica",
                                            "ID_UTENTE":"2",
                                            "ID_APPLICAZIONE":"1",
                                            "utente":
                                            {
                                                    "UTENTE_USERID":"Francesco",
                                                    "UTENTE_ID":"1"
                                            }
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "RATING_DATA":"2011-05-10 14:23:23",
                                            "RATING_VOTO":"1",
                                            "RATING_DESCRIZIONE":"Non ci siamo proprio",
                                            "ID_UTENTE":"3",
                                            "ID_APPLICAZIONE":"1",
                                            "utente":
                                            {
                                                    "UTENTE_USERID":"Luca",
                                                    "UTENTE_ID":"1"
                                            }
                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            }
    }
```

}

That i structured as i want, it's cleaar than there is only one aapplication, with an object developper inside, and an array of object image previews  and an array of rating object with th name of th user that left it. And i can eaasly parse  hi structure with GoogleJson

SO now the question:

Should I modify the initial query to get this final structure? Consider that when php will  be the php side implemeented (i don't know yet how cause I don't have php and java skills :) ) I will go straight from myysql to json so that's what matter to me, that the query is translated as I want.

I know that the question is long and maybe not clear......just ask me for details if you want:)

Comment: This is just ... huge :)

Comment: I know, hope some one can read it anyway and help me :)

Comment: You'd better add a bounty if you expect anyone to sit through that.

Comment: I solved it.....i just had to split the main query in different subqueries and then combine the results as i prefer.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.....i just had to split the main query in different subqueries and then combine the results as i prefer.......If someone want to know more just ask me.